# Changing HTML group class with JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm using an AJAX function to grab some data from a database and run a simple if statement. I want to use the output variable "test" to change the class (and therefore styling) of an SVG group. I was originally using PHP on page load but now that I'm using AJAX I have to use JavaScript and it isn't working.

Here's the AJAX:

```html
  function loadfacebook1()
  {
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
   else
     {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
       var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById("fbname").innerHTML=obj.name;
    document.getElementById("fbtraffic").innerHTML=obj.traffic;
    document.getElementById("fbrevenue").innerHTML=obj.revenue;
    document.getElementById("fbprofit").innerHTML=obj.profit;
    document.getElementById("fbrafrica").innerHTML=obj.rafrica;

    var test = document.getElementById('fbrafrica').value;

    if(test > 100)
     {var africastyle = "b1";
    }

       }
     } 
    
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getfacebook.php",true);
   xmlhttp.send();

  }
```

And here is the group that I'm trying to change the class of:

```html
<g class="<?php echo $africastyle ;?>" transform="translate(0,239) scale(0.016963,-0.016963)">
```

As you can see it uses PHP at the moment but how to I replace this with the JavaScript variable "test" that I assigned in the AJAX function?

Thanks,

Will

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do. Add an ID to your group element.

HTML:

```
<g id="myGroup">
```

JS:

```
if(test > 100){
    var el = document.getElementById('myGroup');
    el.setAttribute('class', 'b1');
}
```

Comment: I thought this would work perfectly but for some reason it still isn't functioning. The style still doesn't change. Is there anything else that you would like to see or any other way I could trouble shoot the issue? I don't think it's a problem with your suggestion - I think you are totally correct. I'm just wondering what else is now going wrong. Thanks

Comment: @WillGreen did you add the id to the group element? and also remove your php stuff? did you check in the dev tools to verify the class is being added? is your css on the page? do you know how to step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: After debugging the site it turns out the problem comes when the array is being parsed. Will update in a moment if I find the source of the problem.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me work out why that is null. Is there a problem with the JSON parse? The value stored in the database is 200.

Comment: It gets to this line: document.getElementById("fbrafrica").innerHTML=obj.rafrica; and then throws an error to say it is null, however when I hover over the obj.rafrica value with my mouse cursor (in the debug window) it reads "200<br". So it know that 200 is stored in the array, it just doesn't seam to be attaching it to document.get...

Comment: @WillGreen is document.getElementById("fbrafrica") null?

Comment: yes, document.getElementById("fbrafrica") is null and it is not meant to be

Comment: you've got #fbrafrica in the HTML?

Comment: No, does it need to be? I have other parses where the element isn't in the html and it works? All I'm trying to do is grab a value from the array, assign it to a JavaScript variable and use that (using the method you provided) to change styling

Comment: I have now corrected this issue but the code you suggested does not seem to be working to change the style. This is my code:     if(test > 100){
        var el = document.getElementById('myGroup');
        el.setAttribute('class', 'b1');
    }

Comment: and this is me applying the id <g id="myGroup" transform="translate(0,239) scale(0.016963,-0.016963)">

Comment: yeah when you use document.getElementById it is looking for that ID in the markup so it makes sense it was null if it wasn't there. Is you javascript after your HTML, or do you have it in a window onload function? Is the class actually being applied to myGroup? Is your code meeting the condition to go into the if statement?